# Holding two fingers touch to enable pointer-events on a DIV doesn't change its behavior until the touch is released

Tags: javascript, css, pointer-events

I'm building a circuit simulator with a canvas layer on top to draw wires and at the bottom a svg layer for interactive inputs. The canvas layer has `pointer-events: none` to allow using svg inputs on bottom (makes it 'transparent' to pointer events). Also, I need set `pointer-events: all` to let user zoom the application by pinch-zoom on mobile.

I'm trying to toggle pointer-events when two fingers are pressed and inmediatly get the behavior that I want on the canvas layer, so I can zoom and move the screen when touch pressing and interact with svg elements when I use just one finger.

There is a way to 'update' the canvas properties without release the fingers? I mean enable pointer-events when I make the two-touch and disable when I release the screen.

I got the change on the canvas layer using touch-events listeners, but the behavior only works until next pointer-event occurs.

```
let canvasC = document.getElementById('cnvParent');
document.addEventListener( 'touchstart', touchScreen );

touchScreen( e ) {
    document.addEventListener( 'touchend', touchEndEl );
    if (e.touches.length > 2) {
      togglePE();
    }
}

togglePE() {
    if (this.zooming) {
      canvasC.style = "pointer-events: none";
      this.zooming = false;
    }
    else {
      canvasC.style = "pointer-events: all";
      this.zooming = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some code, please? It doesn't have to be everything, just a minimally reproducible part to work on.

Comment: I try to emulate the relase and press of touches during my two fingers touch on screen, but it seems like the element doesn't know that its css property has changed